# Junit warning is coming after add to classpath for project specific

Tags: java, junit4

As I add junit4.8.jar to eclipse its showing warning in problem windows.
I Add Junit >>> right click on project-> properties->Java Build Path->libraries->add library
->user library
I am using eclipse helios
Warning is-
Classpath entry org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Junit 4.8 will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.

Please tell me why this warning is coming

Answer (score 1):

It says that you dont export the JUnit Library into the build, and if the build relies on the functionality of that lib, there might occur CNF-Exceptions. As of JUnit there shouldnt be a dependency for your build, right?

As of Eclipse 3.6 just use QuickFix, it will set up the right attributes for you so that the warning should disappear.